# The lambda problem - how to send a constant value through it

Tags: python

Is it possible to send a constant value to a (function-pointer-like) variable that makes use of `lambda`? Here is a very simplified version of what I want to do:

```
for p in range(property):
    property[p].update = lambda s, c: DoUpdate( s, c, p )
```

I would like the third arg `p` to be converted into a constant value. Or to send the value rather than the variable. Is this possible? To have `p` evaluated immediately?

I've seen answers that show to do it this way:

```
for p in range(property):
    property[p].update = lambda s, c, arg=p: DoUpdate( s, c, arg )
```

But I'm getting `TypeError: update keyword: expected a function taking 2 arguments, not 3`

Does this solution not work for Blender specifically? Or maybe I am doing it wrong? Does anyone know of a trick to convince `lambda` to record the value instead of the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works properly in Blender, since it uses a regular Python underneath. The following example uses a lambda with a default argument in order to evaluate the argument during declaration:

```
def test(a, b, c):
    print(f'a = {a}\nb = {b}\nc = {c}')

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = 2

x = lambda a, b, c=len(a): test(a, b, c)
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x(a, b)
```

The lambda uses a default argument for the third parameter, which is evaluated right away. The output is therefore:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = 2
c = 3
```

`c` still has the original length of `a` which was changed after declaring the lambda.

---

The issue that you're having is unrelated to the lambda though. The update callback is expected to take exactly two arguments. This is checked in the properties ([`bpy_props.c`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/python/intern/bpy_props.c)) through:

```
if (bpy_prop_callback_check(update_cb, "update", 2) == -1) {
  return NULL;
}
```

If you can supply a function that takes two arguments it will work properly.

Comment: Have you tried using this setup as a property update function? For some reason, my properties will not register when I do this.

Comment: As the updater for properties of a dynamic class, but a setter would also be ok: `property[p].update = lambda s, c, arg=p: DoUpdate( s, c, arg )` ..It appears that Blender is specifically counting the number of parameters, rather than just trying to call it. Any idea how to solve this situation? I'm still trying to learn Python, but I'm guessing the reason `lambda` works with variables that fall out of scope is because it increases their reference count. Any variable data used in it will remain alive until the `lambda` dies. Is that right? If so, I may be able to take advantage of it.

Comment: Ran out of space. The problem I'm facing is forcing `lambda` to generate a new variable for each property, rather than using the same one each time. If all of the properties use the same temporary variable, they will all end up using the same value (the last one). So I'm hoping there is some way to force a new one to be generated each time.

Comment: I'll investigate this.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts. I'm also playing around with it, but it feels like chasing my tail - or trying to fix the logic of a time travel device. Even if you can think of a way to use global variables in the lambda (a different one per property), that would be helpful. I may end up having to manually assign each lambda outside of a loop. I wonder if its possible to **edit** a lambda after creating it..

Comment: @Robert unless I'm mistaken, your approach doesn't work because the update function is required to have only `self` and `context` as arguments. Using a function with three or more parameters even if they are optional ones, doesn't work. This has nothing to do with lambdas though.

Comment: Like I said, it looks like Blender is counting the number of parameters rather than just trying to call it. I doubt there is anything that can be done with the outside parameters of the lambda, but it may be possible to convince the inside execution code to send unique data for each property. I will continue looking.

Comment: Correct. When you declare a property and pass a update callback function, it will call `bpy_prop_callback_check(update_cb, "update", 2)`(`bpy_props.c`). It checks if you have exactly two arguments.

Comment: Apparently, its as simple as defining the lambda in another function (see other answer)

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the main board, it looks like defining another scope for the lambda will force it to generate a new instance for each use:

```
def MakeUpdateLambda(func,parm):
    return lambda s, c: func( s, c, parm )

for p in range(property):
    property[p].update = MakeUpdateLambda( DoUpdate, p )
```